# Can I know if a javascript file has been executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using a express framework on node and I want to change the value(increase or decrease) of a variable in my testing module each time the module is run. Is there a way to know if the file has been executed and keep it in memory so that next time the file is run again, the value changes again? I want to increase the `variableToChange` each time the module is executed.
Here is my code:

```
    'use strict';

    var util = require('util');
    var makeApiCall = require('proc-utils').makeApiCall; 

    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:' + (require('../../config').port || 3000);

    var url = {
        endpoint: '/patients/register',
        method: 'post'
    };

    var ct = {
        test: function (data, cb) {
            var options = {
                type: 'form',
                data: data,
                baseUrl: baseUrl
            };

            makeApiCall(url.endpoint, url.method, options, cb);
        }
    };

    module.exports = ct;

    //-- Test Code ----------------------------------------------------------
    var variableToChange=0;  
    if (require.main === module) {
        (function () {
            var data = {
                first_name:'John',
                last_name:'Doe',
                email:'shnsdfn'+variableToChange+'b@sh.com',
                password:'John1234'
            };

            ct.test(data, console.log);
        })();
    }
```

Comment: can you add some code ? More details?

Comment: What does "running a file" mean?

Comment: What about making a log file? and use it to report/store previous results of your tests.

Comment: Each time the testing module for the api is executed.

Comment: You just append, like in a log file.

Comment: @Hosni Thanks, maintaining the log file might do the thing. I am new to node and express. So thanks for the help. How do I choose your answer as the chosen answer?

Comment: @Pravin I edit the answer, let us know how you solved your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is storing the information you need in the cookie session:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
express().use(cookieParser()) // include the cookies middleware to parse and manage sessions
.use(session({secret : 'mysecret'}))//set up the session with minimal config (secret)
.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.session.variableToSave = 0; // initialize variable you want to save 
    next(); // starts next middleware
});
```

But this is for storing informations for browser that connects to the server.

Other Solution is maintaining the log file by appending the desired values with other relevant informations to it.

Comment: A cookie session is for storing some information per browser that connects to the server.  It does not seem like that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're probably right but he could have given more informations.

Answer (score 0):

Check app.locals in Express API reference: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals